# Error de bot de discord en python

Tags: python, discord.py, bot

Estoy tratando de hacer un bot de discord con una api de mercado libre, pero estoy hace rato tratando de resolver este error y buscando soluciones, pero nada me da resultados, alguien sabe a que se debe el error?, gracias por su atencion

Código python:

```
import discord
import requests

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!buscar'):
        # Extrae el nombre del producto del mensaje
        product_name = message.content[len('!buscar'):].strip()
    
        # Realiza una solicitud a la API de Mercado Libre para buscar el producto
        search_results = requests.get(f'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q= 
        {product_name}').json()['results']
    
        # Selecciona el producto más barato
        cheapest_product = min(search_results, key=lambda x: x['price'])
    
        # Formatea la respuesta
        response = f'El producto más barato encontrado para "{product_name}" es: "{cheapest_product["title"]}" - ${cheapest_product["price"]} ({cheapest_product["condition"]})\nLink: {cheapest_product["permalink"]}'
    
        # Envía la respuesta al canal
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run('miTokenSecreto')


#token = 'MTA3MTQ3NjEzNjcyNDM5ODE0Mg.Gjlyqm.HH1ub8L7NixNwBiyPJmkcOP95Ryd9cWgbiejYA'
```

El error:

```
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: Primero e importante: si ese token es real, te recomiendo regenerarlo inmediatamente y reportar tu publicación para que borren dicho token. Esto por que los cibercriminales podrían tomar control de tu bot.

Comment: Segundo, el error no concuerda con el código. En tu código pasas el argumento intents como nombrado, pero el error dice que no lo haces. Seguro no lo solucionaste mientras escribías la pregunta?

Comment: Christian, ademas de editar, podriamos reportar a un mod que borre el historial de ediciones. Si no, aun se puede acceder al token. Ademas, te olvidaste de eliminar el comentario con el token.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y solo obtengo un error sobre la línea donde cortas el string. Lo arreglé y tampoco obtengo ese error. Parece un error irreproducible.